# Power Shell service restart failing

Tags: powershell

Below is my code to restart a windows service, the service that I am trying to restart is the service of a third party software that I have installed in my machine.

The `else if` part of the code works properly like when the service is stopped it starts the service but the if part is failing by default like the restart command is stopping the service but it is unable to start the service again.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$service = $args[0]

$servstatus = Get-Service $service.status

if ($servstatus = "Started") {
    Restart-Service $service -Force
} elseif ($servstatus = "Stopped") {
    Start-Service $service -Force
}
```

Comment: I am passing the service name as a parameter from batch file which passes the name into the powershell script as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the event logs to see why the service is failing to start? This isn't a PowerShell issue this is likely an issue with the service.

Answer (score 0):

Status should be `Running`, not `Started`.

Source : `Get-Service`

**AND** equality operator in PS is `-eq` not `=`.

```
$service = $args[0]

$servstatus = Get-Service $service.status

if ($servstatus -eq "Started") {
    Restart-Service $service -Force
} elseif ($servstatus -eq "Stopped") {
    Start-Service $service -Force
}
```

With `=` you are actually assigning a value to `$servstatus`.

Comment: done as per your suggestions still, the script is failing with the below error Restart-Service : Service 'XXX' start failed.
At D:\xyz\Script\test.ps1:15 char:16
+ restart-service <<<<  $service -force
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControl 
   ler:ServiceController) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands 
   .RestartServiceCommand

Answer (score 0):

```
 Restart-Service $args[0]
```

Should be enough. It will start stopped service and restart the running one. 
If you like more verbose code then the following should be used to get the status of the server (plus to fixes by sodawillow):

```
$servstatus = (Get-Service $service).status
```

Comment: I have also tried restarting the service with only, Restart-Service $args[0] but still the service stops and it does not start again throwing the said error.